# Java web Application supporting both Oracle and Mysql database

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have a Java web application currently running on oracle database.i need to support same application on Mysql .In my application we used some oracle specific queries (eg:TRUNC).Please help me to resolve the issue .

Comment: What do you expect here exactly ? If you have specific queries inside your code ; you'll have to change these ...

Comment: thanks for your help .I know some of the oracle functions are not supported in MySql but my application support both oracle and mysql Select TRUNC(sysdate, 'DDD') startDate, sysdate endDate from dua

Comment: It's possible to change the JDBC driver used by your application and the database connection string in order to connect to a MySQL database. But specific queries have to be modified case to case.

Comment: Can you suggest for handling this? We need to maintain both queries for supporting oracle and MySql.How we decide which query running for corresponding to DB.Actually what is the best practice for this

Comment: I would make a specific jar library by database type added to classpath of the web application. If you're using maven, it's even easier with dependencies.

Comment: i have an option to resolve this   if(("oracle"))
{
    query = "select * from ( select * from emp order by sal desc ) where ROWNUM <= 5";
}

else if(("mysql"))
{
    query = "select * from emp order by sal desc limit 0,5";
}   can you tell me any alternative idea

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on you're application architecture but I would prefer using separate jar in order to be more flexible and clearer.

If you can't externalize database queries, you can manage it with conditions but I think it is a little bit too heavy to maintain.

I never had to do something equivalent so there's possibly a better way to do it.